# Dynamic Metric Calculations In Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I am trying to automate some metrics calculation in Oracle. I do have around 50 metrics which need to be calculated basis some low level information. Each metric has a different calculation logic, though they can share underlying data points. I have all calculations text captured in a field along with underlying data points in a table.

I am trying to write a function using dynamic SQL to get the job done. Below is just a code block from the approach which I am following. And for sure, I am not doing it in a correct way, therefore it is prompting errors:

```
DECLARE
    A NUMBER :=10;
    B NUMBER :=20;
    C NUMBER :=40;
    D NUMBER :=35;
    OUTPUT_VAR NUMBER;
    SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+B;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+B+C;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A/D;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A*B;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=B+C;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=C/D;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=B/C;';
    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+D;';
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_TEXT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(OUTPUT_VAR);
END;
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
    A NUMBER :=10;
    B NUMBER :=20;
    C NUMBER :=40;
    D NUMBER :=35;
    OUTPUT_VAR NUMBER;
    SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+B;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+B+C;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A/D;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A*B;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=B+C;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=C/D;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=B/C;';
    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+D;';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_TEXT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(OUTPUT_VAR);
END;
Error report -
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 18
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Request for help to make this work. Your responses are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi  @Deepak.K , the error is normal because you are trying to execute OUTPUT_VAR:=A+D which is not a sql statement. You need to be more concise, because I have no idea what are you trying to accomplish here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it in SQL without PL/SQL is to use XMLTABLE or XMLQUERY.
XQUERY allows you to make simple calculations very easily, for example:

```sql
select * 
from xmltable(
       '$A + $B - $C'
       passing 1 as A, 2 as B, 3 as C
       columns res number path '.'
     );

       RES
----------
         0

select * 
from xmltable(
       '$A + $B * $C'
       passing 1 as A, 2 as B, 3 as C
       columns res number path '.'
     );

       RES
----------
         7
```

So you can easily make dynamic calculations, you just need to add '$' to variable names:

```sql
with
data(a,b,c,d) as (
   select 1,1,1,1 from dual union all
   select 1,2,3,4 from dual union all
   select 5,5,5,5 from dual 
)
,calc(id, expression) as (
    select 1, 'A + B' from dual union all
    select 2, 'A + B - C' from dual union all
    select 3, 'A * B * C' from dual union all
    select 4, '(A + B) * C - D' from dual
)
select
   *
from
    data d
   ,calc c
   ,xmltable(
        (regexp_replace(c.expression,'(\w)','$\1'))
        passing
            d.A as A,
            d.B as B,
            d.C as C,
            d.D as D
        columns
            res number path '.'
   ) x;

         A          B          C          D         ID EXPRESSION             RES
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ----------
         1          1          1          1          1 A + B                    2
         1          1          1          1          2 A + B - C                1
         1          1          1          1          3 A * B * C                1
         1          1          1          1          4 (A + B) * C - D          1
         1          2          3          4          1 A + B                    3
         1          2          3          4          2 A + B - C                0
         1          2          3          4          3 A * B * C                6
         1          2          3          4          4 (A + B) * C - D          5
         5          5          5          5          1 A + B                   10
         5          5          5          5          2 A + B - C                5
         5          5          5          5          3 A * B * C              125
         5          5          5          5          4 (A + B) * C - D         45

12 rows selected.
```

---

---

PS
Note, you need a space before '-'sign, because otherwise it will be considered as 'B-' variable:

```sql
SQL> select * from xmltable('$A+$B-$C' passing 1 as A, 2 as B, 3 as C columns res number path '.');
select * from xmltable('$A+$B-$C' passing 1 as A, 2 as B, 3 as C columns res number path '.')
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-19228: XPST0008 - undeclared identifier: prefix 'B-' local-name ''
```

Comment: Thanks @Sayan Malakshinov, you are a champion. It works too.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
DECLARE
    A NUMBER :=10;
    B NUMBER :=20;
    C NUMBER :=40;
    D NUMBER :=35;
    OUTPUT_VAR NUMBER;
    SQL_TEXT VARCHAR2(50);
function calc(p_cmd in varchar2) return number as
   res number;
begin
    execute immediate '
       Declare
           A NUMBER :=:a;
           B NUMBER :=:b;
           C NUMBER :=:c;
           D NUMBER :=:d;
           OUTPUT_VAR number;
        Begin 
           '||p_cmd||'  
           :res:= output_var; 
        end;' 
        Using a, b, c, d, out res;
     Return res;
End;
BEGIN
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+B;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+B+C;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A/D;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A*B;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=B+C;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=C/D;';
--    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=B/C;';
    SQL_TEXT:='OUTPUT_VAR:=A+D;';
    
    OUTPUT_VAR:=calc(SQL_TEXT) ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OUTPUT_VAR);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you @Sayan Malakshinov. I tried running this code but encountered with following error:

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 18, column 27:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 10, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 19, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 19, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @Deepak.K sorry, typed on my phone. Fixed now

Comment: Thank you @Sayan Malakshinov, it worked and solved my purpose.

Comment: Hi @Sayan Malakshinov the code you provided works well, however just wanted to check if there is any possibility for this function can be used inside a SELECT statement.

Comment: hi @Deepak.K I've added another answer with a variant for simple calculations in SQL without extra pl/sql functions.